# complicate mySQL query for multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have tables:

```
|**USER**|
|--------|
| _id    |
| name   |
----------
```

next:

```
|**PHOTO**|
| _id     |
| user    | - integer FK
-----------
```

next:

```
|**RATING**|
| user     | - integer FK
| photo    | - integer FK
| seen     |
------------
```

And all I could do is extract data like:

```
|**USER**|**PHOTO**|**SEEN**|
|--------|---------|--------|
|   1    |   100   |   0    |
|   2    |   100   |   0    |
-----------------------------
```

My question: Is there any way to extract:

```
|**USER**|**PHOTO**|**SEEN**|
|--------|---------|--------|
|  name  |   100   |   0    |
| name_2 |   100   |   0    |
-----------------------------
```

in this table:

**USER** - refers to user **WHO** voted

**PHOTO** - refers to photo on which user have voted, **BUT** it has to be PHOTO of user with _id=2 (for example)

**SEEN** - refers only to that row

Imagine function:

```
function get_new_votes($myID){
....
}
```

Any help ?

EDIT:

for example:

```
USER
_id   |   name
----------------------
1     |   random name
2     |   different name

PHOTO
_id   |   user
-----------------
100   |   1

RATING
user  |   photo   |   seen
------------------------------
2     |   100     |    0
```

I want to extract all record with PHOTO that uploaded user _id = 1

```
different name   |  100   |   0
```

Comment: What does your code look like that gets your current extracted data?

Comment: SELECT r.user,r.photo, r.seen FROM rating r, user u, photo p
WHERE r.photo=p._id AND p.user=u._id AND u._id='$myId'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with an `INNER JOIN` in SQL:

```
SELECT u.name, r.photo, r.seen
FROM rating AS r
INNER JOIN user AS u
ON r.user = u._id
INNER JOIN photo AS p
ON r.photo = p._id
WHERE p.user = <userId>
```

Comment: Sorry, this isn't working as I want to. Please, look to my Post, at the end there's exactly what i want :)